# Error not found value in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Schema:

```
root
 |-- col_a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col_b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col_c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)
```

Code to break the struct of (col_a)

```
df = df.select($"col_a.*",$"col_b",$"col_c")
df.printSchema()
```

Op:

```
|-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)
|-- col_b: string (nullable = true)
|-- col_c: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)
```

Now when I am trying to select only the first column ("$numberLong") and rename it

```
df = df.select($"$numberLong".as("test"))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: not found: value numberLong
df = df.select($"$numberLong")
                  ^
```

When the column is clearly there I am not able to understand the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a column has a leading `$` in its column name, you can't reference the column by `$"colName"` - not even if you have colName enclosed by `backticks`.  Rather, use `col("colName")` as shown below:

```
case class A(`$numberLong`: String)

val df = Seq(
  (A("x1"), "d1", A("y1")),
  (A("x2"), "d2", A("y2")),
  (A("x3"), "d3", A("y3"))
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c")

val df2 = df.select($"col_a.*", $"col_b", $"col_c")

df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- col_b: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- col_c: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- $numberLong: string (nullable = true)

df2.select(col("$numberLong").as("test")).printSchema
// root
//  |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```